# Reductions of structure groups and sections of coset bundles

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, principal-bundles

I'm looking for a reference for the following proposition:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a (closed) Lie subgroup of $G$.  Let $E \to B$ be a principal $G$-bundle.  Then reductions of the structure group from $G$ to $H$ of $E$ are in bijective correspondence with sections of the $G/H$-bundle $E/H \to B$.

I want to know all about the details of the argument, so a more comprehensive source is preferred.

Comment: I would say that Chapter 6 of the classical Husemoller "Fibre Bundles" deals exactly with this point.

Comment: @N.Ciccoli Thanks!  Theorem 6.2.3 is exactly what I was looking for.